# Binding textbox enter press to reactive command

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a textbox bound to a view model with the following XAML:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="usrTxt" Text="{Binding UserID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Margin="0,0,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="50"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ToolTip="User ID" FontSize="29.333" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="15,0" TabIndex="0">
      <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding EntrCommand}"/>
      </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

I'm trying to create a `ReactiveCommand` in my view model that will trigger whenever the `KeyBinding` event in the view is fired.  I'm positive that I have the syntax wrong for this, but I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it after looking at the docs.  Here's my relevant view model code:

```
class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
      private DbContext dbCtx;

      public MainViewModel()
      {
          dbCtx = new DbContext(Properties.Settings.Default.DbString);

          EnterCmd = this.WhenAny(x => x.UserID, x => x.Value)
                .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .Do(_ => IsLoading = true);

          EnterCmd.Subscribe(x =>
          {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                IsLoading = false;
          });
      }

      public ReactiveCommand EnterCmd { get; private set; }

      ...
}
```

An obvious problem is that `WhenAny` returns `System.IObservable<string>` where as `EnterCmd` expects type `ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand`.  Another problem I noticed is that I can't declare `EnterCmd` with a getter and setter because I got the error `'ReactiveCommand': static types cannot be used as parameters.`  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Command="{Binding EntrCommand} it must be a typo..pls edit this

Comment: @shreesha It's not a typo. I assumed that `{Binding EntrCommand}` would map to that property I have in my view model called `EntrCommand`.  That may not be the correct way to do this, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper syntax for RxUI command:

```
    public ReactiveCommand<object> EnterCmd { get; private set; }
    ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading { get { return _isLoading.Value; } }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        EnterCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(
            this.WhenAny(x => x.UserID, x => x.Value)
                .Select(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));

        EnterCmd.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsLoading, out _isLoading);

        EnterCmd.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        });
```

ReactiveCommand is a static helper class (factory methods mostly), the real type is the generic version of it.

Comment: This looks great.  My only other issue then is how to convert `<KeyBinding Command="{Binding EnterCmd}"/>` in my view so that when I press enter, that command subscription is triggered.  Any ideas?

Comment: I should probably give more detail...  `Console.WriteLine(x)` actually IS being called when I press enter, as expected, but the value is empty.  How do I access the actual string from `x`?  I tried `x.Value` but that doesn't seem to be a valid option.

Comment: You should access it from the VM, relying on the command parameter isn't [recommended](http://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concepts/commands/). In your case `Console.WriteLine(UserID)`

Answer (score 0):

Use such reactiveCommand then:

```
public class ReactiveCommand : ICommand, IObservable<object>
{
    private bool _canExecute = true;
    private readonly Subject<object> _execute = new Subject<object>();

    public ReactiveCommand(IObservable<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (canExecute != null)
        {
            canExecute.Subscribe(x => this._canExecute = x);
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this._canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._execute.OnNext(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<object> observer)
    {
        return this._execute.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do you have any example of how I can implement this into my current codebase?  I'm not sure how to do so based on the example you gave.